# Dynamic close button on search bar using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, textbox

When I enter some value in search text box, the `[X]` close button dynamically appear in the left corner of the text box and I need to clear and search results when I click the `[X]` close button using AnglarJS.

Example - Exactly like in Microsoft Outlook email search.

[image]

Comment: if you have `ng-model="text"` on your input filed, then you simply need to add `ng-click="text=''"` on your `[X]` button

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display the X, you'll need to use `ng-show` to only show it when there's content in the input and `ng-click` to bind the clear text logic, as such:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <input type="text" ng-model="text">
  <span ng-show="text" ng-click="text='';">X</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) @Protozoid